# Как работает try... except?

Tags: delphi, исключения, delphi-7

Как вообще работает этот блок? Нашел простой код его применения, привязал к кнопке, но он мне выдает ошибку, что-то там by zero (я так понял типа на ноль нельзя делить) и приходиться сбрасывать работу программы...

```
var
    number, zero: Integer;
begin
    // Попытка делить целое число на ноль - чтобы поднять исключение
    try
        zero := 0;
        number := 1 div zero;
        ShowMessage('number / zero = '+IntToStr(number));
    except
        ShowMessage('Неизвестная ошибка');
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Это очень полезный инструмент ,и, кроме того, очень распространенный. Не знаю, как вы искали в гугле, если ничего не нашли на эту тему...

Конструкция

```
Try -> EXCEPT -> END
```

управляет поведением возможной исключительной ситуацией, которая может возникнуть в секции "TRY".  Если такая возникает, то выполнение кода в секции "TRY" прекращается и моментально перепрыгивает в начало секции "EXCEPT" и код, находящийся там, выполняется до конца, т.е до "END". Рассмотрим пример обработки исключительной ситуацией "EZeroDevide"(деление на ноль) :

```
...
var
  a: integer;
  ...
begin
  try
    a := 1/0; 
  except
    on EZeroDivide do showmessage('Divide by zero not allowed!'); // обработка КОНКРЕТНОЙ исключителной ситуации
  end;
end;
```

Также существует еще одна конструкция обработки исключительных ситуаций:

```
TRY -> FINALLY -> END
```

Данный блок функционирует немного иначе: если в секции "TRY" возникнет исключительная ситуация, то выполнение кода оставновится в этой секции и перепрыгнет в секцию "FINALLY".
Но даже если никакой исключительной ситуации не возникнет, то в конце выполнения кода в "TRY", секция "FINALLY" все равно будет выполнена. Эту конструкцию уместно применять, если в конце работы надо произвести операции по, например, освобождению памяти. Пример:

**1 случай:**

```
...
try
  a := 1/0; 
finally
  showmessage('Divide by zero not allowed!');
end;
...
```

**2 случай:**

```
...
try
  a := 1/1; 
finally
  showmessage('Divide by zero not allowed!');
end;
...
```

В обоих случаях будет выведено сообщение.

Comment: спасибо большое, коротко и ясно, но всё же у меня отладчик выдает такое:  raised exception class EDivByZero with message "Division by zero". Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue. Почитал про эту ошибку на форуме каком то, там человек пишет: 
"Ищи ошибку в конструкторе Tvrag и дочерних. Есть другая версия, по которой, на момент создания Tvrag, Dxspriteengine1 не существует. Решается 2 способами - поместить код в onShow или вручную создавать Dxspriteengine1."
  ох как я до этого еще не дорос:)(я только учусь)

Comment: На самом деле так и должно быть! Если вы запускаете программу под отладчиком( F9 ), то всякие похожие блоки просто игнорятся. Запустите непосредственно сам скомпилированный EXE файл

Comment: и вправду:) спасибо большое)

Comment: Поправка для потомков: подобные блоки не игнорятся. Просто отладчик срабатывает раньше (это называется first-chance exceptions). Но если продолжить выполнение программы, то блок except отработает успешно.

Answer (score 0):

Запустите ваш проект(ехе файл) вне Делфи и блок сработает. Просто транслятор раньше вашего блока перхватывает ошибу