# Почему не происходит обработка исключений?

Tags: delphi, исключения, delphi-7

Программа запускается как из Delphi так и без него (обычным двойным кликом, дабы исключить ошибки настройки среды).
Написана (компилируется) на Delphi 7.

Код простой. Сообщение - Возникло исключение не появляется. Никогда.
Любой код в секции except не выполняется.
Если вынести код `c:=a div b;` за пределы try-except (например выше) программа сообщит Division by zero.
Почему не происходит обработка исключений?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a,b,c:integer;
begin
  a:=1;
  b:=0;
  try
    c:=a div b;
  except
    ShowMessage('Возникло исключение.'); //Это сообщение не появляется
    //ShowMessage(inttostr(c)); //Раскомментировав эту строку мы получим сразу 2 сообщения. Исключения заработали??
  end;
end;
```

PS

Моя задача при любых ошибках (и только ошибках) в одной секции кода, гарантировано выполнять другую секцию кода.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работает try... except?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/108582/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-try-except)

Comment: @PavelMayorov не дубликат и ошибка не в этом. Смотрите мой ответ. Это достаточно частая проблема с оптимизациями.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема на 99% в том, что у вас по умолчанию включены оптимизации компилятора в настройках проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компилятор видит, что нигде не происходит обращение к вычисленной переменной `с`, и исключает все строки относящиеся к ее вычислению. Соответственно `c:=a div b;` не выполняется и исключение не происходит.

Если же вы выводите `ShowMessage(inttostr(c));`, то компилятор видит, что `c` используется и собирает все строки, и выполняет `c:=a div b;`, что вызывает исключение и показ 2 сообщений, как вы наблюдаете.

Вы можете увидеть, какие строки были скомпилированы, по синей точке слева от них, после сборки/компиляции проекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также компилятор выдает предупреждения:

> [Hint] Unit1.pas(30): Value assigned to 'c' never used
>   [Hint] Unit1.pas(28): Value assigned to 'b' never used
>   [Hint] Unit1.pas(27): Value assigned to 'a' never used

Comment: Надо бы еще рассказать про `{$O-}`

Comment: @PavelMayorov по сути это одно и то же, но если вы добавите, то буду благодарен )

Comment: "Компилятор видит, что нигде не происходит обращение к вычисленной переменной с, и исключает все строки относящиеся к ее вычислению"

Очень интересное поведение компилятора, не выполнять действие если его результат не используется в дальнейшем.

Отсутствие использование результата от действия, автоматически исключает действие из программы.

Мне кажется это не верно.
Навскидку
Использование переменных-происходит в памяти.
Действие не будет выполнено-в памяти не будет переменной/её нового значения.

По данному адресу памяти может быть обращение другой программы. А там ничего нет.

Comment: @Иван думаю, что взятие указателя будет достаточным, для того чтобы компилятор не исключал работу с переменной (проверил, так и происходит). Обращение к памяти переменной (не массива/структуры!) не по указателю - граничит с undefined behavior.